# Как сохранить данные функции?

Tags: lua, minecraft

У меня есть функция, которая создаёт `progressbar`:

```
function progressbar(value, x, y, text, update)
    if update == 0 then
    local border1 = glassesTerminal.addBox2D();
    border1.setSize(100, 1)
    border1.addTranslation(x, y-1, 0)
    border1.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    border1.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)

    local border2 = glassesTerminal.addBox2D();
    border2.setSize(100, 1)
    border2.addTranslation(x, y+15, 0)
    border2.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    border2.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)

    local border3 = glassesTerminal.addBox2D();
    border3.setSize(1, 15)  
    border3.addTranslation(x-1, y, 0)
    border3.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    border3.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)

    local border4 = glassesTerminal.addBox2D();
    border4.setSize(1, 15)
    border4.addTranslation(x+100, y, 0)
    border4.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    border4.addColor(0, 0, 0, 1)


    local bar = glassesTerminal.addBox2D();
    bar.setSize(value, 15)
    bar.addTranslation(x, y, 0)
    if value >= 90 then
            bar.addColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5)
            bar.addColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5)        
        else
            bar.addColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
            bar.addColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
    end

    local text_p = glassesTerminal.addText2D()
    text_p.setText(text)
    text_p.setFont("")
    text_p.setFontSize(8)
    text_p.addTranslation(x+5, y+2.5, 0)
    end

    if update == 1 then
        text_p.setText(text)
        bar.setSize(value, 15)
        if value >= 90 then
            bar.addColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5)
            bar.addColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5)        
        else
            bar.addColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
            bar.addColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5)
    end
    end
end

local p_energy = progressbar(value_energy, 15, 25, energy_reactor, 0)
local p_heat = progressbar(value_heat, 15, 50, heat_reactor, 0)

while i < 1 do
    os.sleep(1)
    p_energy = progressbar(value_energy, 15, 25, energy_reactor, 1)
    p_heat = progressbar(value_heat, 15, 50, heat_reactor, 1)
end
```

Если использовать один `progressbar`, то всё работает. Но если создать два `progressbar'a`, то новые значения объявляются только на втором `progressbar'e` в цикле. Без цикла вроде всё нормально работает.
Почему так происходит?

Использую следующие моды:

`OpenComputers` - https://github.com/MightyPirates/OpenComputers

`OpenGlasses2` - https://github.com/StarChasers/OCGlasses/wiki

P.S: Оказывается, что при создании второго `progressbar'a`, данные первого перезаписываются и удаляются.

Comment: К вас какая-то ерунда написана... Функция (?) progressbar у вас ни при каких обстоятельствах ничего не возвращает, но в коде, почему-то вы используете ее возврат. Во-вторых, почему вы в цикле используете эту же функцию? Я не понимаю как в вашем представлении это должно работать

Comment: Приведите пример кода который вы не понимаете из нескольких строчек, чтобы любой мог его воспроизвести и понять о чём вы говорите. Почему вы считаете что отвечающие должны играть в вашу игру, изучать api её модов и ваш код?